# Create sqlite3 database from .sql file

Tags: sqlite, cygwin, red5

The goal is to make a database out of a .sql file.

I'm trying to set up a local environment to test and modify this red5 implementation

Step 1 is

`Create a database using the SQL command in database/database.sql`

I'm on Windows, so I'm on Cygwin, with sqlite3 and a few other things installed, so I figured I'd make a database out of that.

When I try to load the file (That I moved) in an effort to make a database out of it, I get this.

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .load database.sql
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've googled around and this seems to be a problem with the file path to the application.

The actual path is `D:\cygwin\home\Houseman\database.sql`

I'm in my home directory when I run `sqlite3`, so it should be right there, and accessible.

How can I do this?

Also, if there's a better way about setting up a temporary database so that I can test this application that is, apparently, dependent upon databases, that'd be helpful too.

Thanks

---

My database.sql file is

```
   CREATE TABLE `vpVideo` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vidExists` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I do `.read database.sql` I get

`Error: near line 1: near "unsigned": syntax error`

---

So I took out the `unsigned` and the `ENGINE=myISAM` stuff, as well as the `AUTO_INCREMENT`  and now It seems to work.

At least it doesn't throw errors when I do `.read`

So I think it worked. Can I view a file somewhere to see the result?

Comment: did you try `sqlite> .read <filename>`

Comment: @matthiasLuag No I didn't... But now I did and I get a syntax error. I'll update my question

Comment: mh is the sql exported from a sqlite database? Sqlite (as do other vendors of sql databases) extended the standard SQL-92 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) syntax so that exports may not be cross compatible between different vendors of databases

Comment: @MatthiasLaug I don't even know

Comment: ok since your have `MyISAM` in your export, it seems to be from MySQL.  Remove the entire stuff `ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` and remove the `unsigned`

Comment: Since `sqlite3` is a Cygwin executable, it uses Cygwin-style paths, not Windows-style paths, `D:\cygwin\home\Houseman\database.sql` is `/home/Houseman/database.sql` (assuming you installed Cygwin at `D:\Cygwin`). But I don't think that's related to your problem.

Comment: @MatthiasLaug Okay, we're making progress, but now I get a new error. Will update question.

Comment: Probably `sqlite3` just doesn't support some of the syntax in your file (as others have said in more detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exports is taken from a MySQL database hence the `MyISAM`. This will work for you

```
CREATE TABLE vpVideo (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  userID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createDate bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  vidExists varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

AUTOINCREMENT is done automatically with the [definition of your primary key](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Imports between different databases only work if it is done with the SQL-92 standard. All vendors of databases extended that standard, so that [SQL-92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) is only a subset of the entire sqlite syntax (as it is for others like oracle, db2, mysql)

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I'm assuming that MySQL syntax is a bit different than sqlite?  

So `.read` works. Did it create my database with `.read`?

Comment: exactly, I added the explantation for different sql syntax

Comment: Thanks. One more thing where might my database be stored, so I can link my project to it later?

Comment: hehe :) start sqlite with `sqlite3 mydatabase.db` and it will be right in your current path